# google chrome exit kiosk mode to desktop mode

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk

hi im working with chrome app as `pos` application ..
now i dont want the user to quit the page while he selling staff ..
and i dont want him to use f5 to refresh page ..
so i start chrome using `kisok` mode
like this ..

```
--kiosk-printing --kiosk  "https://your-shop-name.shoptill-e.com/builder/pos.php"
```

but sometimes when the user shift end i need to exit kiosk mode to desktop mode
is it possible to do that using js code or anything ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems Chrome still does not support to exit kiosk mode. see https://superuser.com/a/816889.

But Microsoft Edge allow you restart the session in kiosk, it also support to restart session automatically by using `--kiosk-idle-timeout-minutes`. [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode)